# What is the meaning of "BODA"?

Tags: atlas-v

What is the meaning of the acronym **BODA**  as used in an *Atlas V* launch, specifically the Juno launch in 2011?

Comment: Please provide the citation to where precisely you saw this term used for the Juno launch.

Comment: BODA was announced at roughly 1:45 into the Juno launch [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4J7dCdZufg) . SRB chamber pressures had peaked. Then SRB roll-off. Then main engine throttle up after BODA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BODA appears to stand for "burn-out detection algorithm".

During the launch of an Atlas V equipped with solid rocket boosters, the main engine throttles down after about 75 seconds to limit g-force. Once the *burn-out* of the solid rockets is *detected*, the main engine throttles back up to 100%.

I'm not sure if the algorithm is based on determination of pressure inside the booster casings, or on accelerometer readings, or tracking of the trajectory from the ground, or some combination thereof.

(This was a tough one to work out. The acronym expansion was given in [this list](http://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series13/DeepCommo_Acro_Abbrev--141029.pdf) but with no further explanation. Launch timelines like [this one for New Horizons](http://www.hwupgrade.it/forum/archive/index.php/.../t-1112682.html) mention burnout detection without use of the acronym.)